# Netezza SQL - order by an aggregate output

Tags: sql, sas, netezza

```
Select date, count(*) as volume
from table
group by date
order by 2
or
order by count
or
order by count(*)
```

The order by doesn't work for any of options above. I want order by volume

Can you help??

Comment: What happens when you try each of these? (I would expect `order by 2` to work.) Also, it's a very bad idea to use reserved words (date, count) as column names in SQL.

Comment: Yeah sorry, it was just example. I've used volume instead of count. the order by 2 works for just sql but not netezza for some reason.

Comment: CREATE TABLE VOLUMES AS
   SELECT substring(to_char(START_DATE,'0000'),2,2)||'/'||substring(to_char(START_DATE,'0000'),4,2) as DATE
     ,COUNT(*) as VOLUME                                     
   FROM  CDS
   WHERE                                                                                                                     
   AND (START_DATE - ((DATE/100) * 100)) IN (3,4)
   GROUP BY DATE                                             
   ORDER BY 2

Comment: Why are you trying to include an `ORDER BY` in a create table statement?

Comment: Post code that reveals your error. Use answer box for responses. This helps everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried all the three queries on my Netezza and only two of them are working.

-- Working fine

```
   SELECT DATE, COUNT(*) AS VOLUME
   FROM TABLE
   GROUP BY DATE
   ORDER BY 2;
```

-- Working fine

```
   SELECT DATE, COUNT(*) AS VOLUME
   FROM TABLE
   GROUP BY DATE
   ORDER BY COUNT(*)
```

-- This is not working because Order by Column doesn't exist in the select clause.

```
   SELECT DATE, COUNT(*) AS VOLUME
   FROM TABLE
   GROUP BY DATE
   ORDER BY COUNT;
```